# TypeError: render is not a function while calling and rendering data from API

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

So, I am creating a movie app in React JS and while rendering a component based on the data fetched from API, I am getting this error

> render is not a function TypeError: render is not a function

[image: error i am getting]

Here's my code, totally working for `TvListProvider` but getting error for `TopRatedProvider`

```
export const TvListProvider = ({ render }) => {
  const url_tv = `${BASE_URL}/3/trending/tv/day?api_key=${API_KEY}`;

  const { data: tv, isLoading, isError } = useDataProvider(url_tv);
  console.log(typeof render);

  return (
    <Suspense fallback={<div>Loading...</div>}>
      {render({ tv, isLoading, isError })}
    </Suspense>
  );
};

export const TopRatedProvider = ({ render }) => {
  const url_topRated = `${BASE_URL}/3/movie/top_rated?api_key=${API_KEY}`;

  const { data: topRated, isLoading, isError } = useDataProvider(url_topRated);

  return (
    <Suspense fallback={<div>Loading...</div>}>
      {render({ topRated, isLoading, isError })}
    </Suspense>
  );
};
```

and here is how i am using this

```
<TopRatedProvider
   render={({ topRated, isError }) => (
     <ListComponent data={topRated} isError={isError} />
   )}
/>
```

I tried all the search engines, all the AI but still couldn't figure out the solution

Edit: adding the actual api call for more clarification

```
useEffect(() => {
    const fetchData = async () => {
      setIsLoading(true);
      setError(null);

      if (cache[url]) {
        setData(cache[url]);
        setIsLoading(false);
      } else {
        try {
          const result = await axios(url);
          const responseData = result.data.results
            ? result.data.results
            : result.data;
          setData(responseData);
          cache[url] = responseData;
        } catch (error) {
          setError(error.message);
        } finally {
          setIsLoading(false);
        }
      }
    };

    fetchData();
  }, [url]);

  return { data, isLoading, error };
};
```

Comment: Is that the only place you're using `<TopRatedProvider />`?

Comment: @Phil, yes it is the only place

Comment: Could you provide a log like this
export const TopRatedProvider = ({ render }) => {
console.log(typeof render)
console.log(JSON.stringify(render,null,2))

Comment: @RenaudReguieg, log is what I share in the image above, please refer to that and when i try to get the type of `render` then I am getting `undefined` for this particular case only

Comment: Could you provide the steps you do to get to that error ? Based on your message, I assume You are not using typescript ? 
Are you running your app in dev mode or the built one with serve ?

Comment: @RenaudReguieg, i am using `jsx` and is currently running `locally`. Here's where i have deployed it `https://epic-cinema.vercel.app`

in the left drawer you can see that, go to the console for the error message

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The issue was a logical one; you were passing a child component, i.e., TopRatedProvider to the Route instead of the parent wrapper, i.e., TopIMDB which passes the actual values of the required props. I suggest using typescript in future projects, as errors like this can be caught at compile time.

Comment: added the actual api call but again same thing is totally working fine for tv

Comment: Have you been able to fix the issue @mnkkhan77?

Comment: nope, I removed that component completely 

Comment: Ok no problem, you can reach out to me whenever if you have any issues in the future.